# Redirecting to controller in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have a function, practiceTest, ran in my view that I want to set up an event handler on for the keyup event.  If the key pressed is equal to 'f' or 'j' it then checks if that is the correct answer, at which point, if it is, it performs a series of action.  If not, I wanted it to send the variable 'incorrect' back to the controller, where it will be redirected to another page.  The problem that is occuring is that the it seems to continuously cycle back to my practiceTest controller, as if the answer was incorrect, but it does so before an event even occurs.  Nothing shows in the browser, and the Network tab in Chrome Develper tools just shows a continous cycle to the PracticeTest controller. Any ideas?

practiceTest function:

```
function practiceTask(counter, test_key, test_id){

  setTimeout(function(){ display(counter, test_key)}, 500);

  function display(counter, test_key){

    $('#imageLocation').attr("src", 'sample');
    $('#imageLocation').show();
    start = new Date();

    $(document).on("keyup", function(e){
      guess = String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase();
      if (counter < test_key.length){
        if (guess == 'f' || guess == 'j'){
          if (guess == test_key[counter].answer){
              console.log(counter);
              console.log(test_key[counter]);
              $(document).off('keyup');
              $('#imageLocation').hide();
              counter++;
              practiceTask(counter, test_key, test_id); 
            }
          else{
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: '<?php echo site_url('practiceTest'); ?>',
              data: {incorrect: 1},
              success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
              }
            });
            <?php redirect(site_url('practiceTest'), 'refresh') ?>;*/
          }
        }
      }
    });         
  }
}
```

PracticeTestController:

```
class PracticeTest extends CI_Controller{

    function index(){

        $this->load->model('sample_practice');
        $incorrect = $this->input->post('incorrect');
        $data['incorrect'] = $incorrect;
        $test_id = 1;

        if ($incorrect){
           $this->load->view('practice_incorrect_view.php', $data);
        }
        else{
           $json_key = $this->sample_practice->getKey($test_id);

           $json_key = json_decode($json_key, true);
           shuffle($json_key);

           $data['test_key'] = $json_key;
           $data['test_id'] = $test_id;

           $this->load->view("practice_test_view.php", $data);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help.  Any ideas on how to better implement this are always appreciated as well.

**EDIT:**

If I use

```
window.location.href = '<?php echo site_url('practiceTest'); ?>';
```

inside of the success function in the AJAX call, it works, but then in the controller, the conditional that checks to see if $incorrect == 1 doesn't seem to working.  The controller loads the practice_test_view, and not the practice_incorrect_view.

**SOLUTION:**

At least for my instance, by applying what I said in the EDIT above, but redirecting to a different function in the controller, and that function pointed to the practice_incorrect_view that I wished to display, it worked.

Comment: Most probably your js codeflow is entering the `<?php redirect(site_url('practiceTest'), 'refresh') ?>` block everytime. Try to do an `alert("text")` there initially. When you are sure it works perfectly, replace it with the redirect code.

Comment: I tried this.  When I have the console.log in place of the redirect, it works perfectly, with the log firing whenever a wrong guess occurs.  However, as soon as I replace it with the redirect, it goes back to the continuous cycle.  It appears as if the redirect is firing immediately each time, despite being inside a conditional, which is inside an event handler.  It's weird...